# How to store answer from prompt and use it?

Tags: javascript, html, keypress, prompt, tampermonkey

I want to create an autologout script where it prompts you to enter any key. That key will be the key that is listened for so when that key is pressed the code stimulates a click that clicks the logout button. This script is ran from tampermonkey. The code below is what I have so far and tried but doesn't work.

```
const logkey = document.getElementById("logoutButton")

function logout() {
logkey.click()
    logkey.submit()
};

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == key) {
    logkey.click()
      logkey.submit()
      logout()
  }
});


    <button id="loginButton" type="button" class="auth-btn btn btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
    <button id="registerButton" type="button" class="auth-btn btn btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button>
    <button id="logoutButton" type="button" class="auth-btn btn btn-lg" style="display:none" onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Edit: I have thought about  calling the function of logging out when the key from the prompt question is clicked and if that was possible how would you go on about doing that?

```
const key = prompt("Type in any key on your keyboard. This will be the key that will be used to logout")


document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == key) {

      logout()

  }
});
```

Comment: What is the logout button not doing? not calling the listener again? Can you show a little more code? Like why do you need to click the button and not just call the function in the listener

Comment: the logout button is logging you out of your account so then it would just display login and register. how would you call the function if it is inside of the webpage? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The event listener is registered within the function `logout()`. This means that the event listener will not execute until `logout` is called once. The only way to register the event listener is to click the button, which is invisible.

```
function logout() {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == key) {
      logkey.click()
    }
  });
};
```

The event listener needs to be executed outside of the function `logout()`, like so:

```
function logout() {
  // logout code here
};

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == key) {
    logkey.click()
  }
});
```